# SharePoint Mobile App. Logging into 2013 SharePoint with exchange server

Tags: office, mobile, exchange-server, exchange

When attempting to log into the SharePoint Mobile app, it asks for credentials.

The problem is that unlike the Outlook mobile app, it does not allow you to choose an exchange server, so that you can enter the server info and domain, allowing you to log in to your domain account.

The SharePoint version is 2013. Is there a way to log into the app? Am I missing something obvious? If all else fails I will just use the mobile browser to access sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SharePoint on-prem, you enter your credentials in the format of `DOMAIN\UserName`.

The app only supports NTLM authentication, so you need to make sure that your Web App is configured for that and you do not have a pre-authentication reverse proxy.

Comment: So when prompted for an email address I should use DOMAIN\UserName? Once I put in my domain account it prompts me for the SharePoint business server.

Comment: Yes, you would then put in your Web Application URL.